# Terraform fail to download existing bitnami chart

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, terraform, kubernetes-helm, bitnami, kubernetes-jenkins-plugin

I am planning to setup jenkins pipeline on K8S using terraform to provising my CI/CD environment.

I am using **Terraform v0.12.18**

My terraform file has following **resource**

```
resource "helm_release" "jenkins-master" {
  name = "jenkins"
  chart = "jenkins"
  version = "7.0.3"
  repository = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"


  set {
    name = "jenkinsUser"
    value = "admin"
  }
  set {
    name = "jenkinsPassword"
    value = "admin"
  }
}
```

When I ran
**terraform apply -input=false provision-plan**

I am getting following error.

```
Error: failed to download "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami/jenkins-7.0.3.tgz" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)
```

But when I ran direct helm install using

**helm install my-jenkins bitnami/jenkins --version 7.0.3**

then jenkins get install.

If I click on the linke **https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami/jenkins-7.0.3.tgz** then also I am able to download the chart.

Can someone please helm to find the issue ?

Thanks
Alpesh

Answer (score 7):

The issue is caused because helm-terraform-provider uses `verify = true` by default.

The equivalent helm command would be

```
helm install my-jenkins bitnami/jenkins --version 7.0.3 --verify --debug
```

Which will triggers the following error:

```
> helm install my-jenkins bitnami/jenkins --version 7.0.3 --verify --debug
install.go:172: [debug] Original chart version: "7.0.3"
Error: failed to fetch provenance "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami/jenkins-7.0.3.tgz.prov"
helm.go:81: [debug] failed to fetch provenance "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami/jenkins-7.0.3.tgz.prov"
```

This is an issue with the upstream chart and we are looking into it.

As a temporary workaround, setting `verify = false` should fix the issue.

If the problem persists, adding **HELM_DEBUG=1** to your terraform apply command would provide helpful information to determine the root cause of the issue.

Comment: I tried with verify=false but still the issue is same

Comment: I am not sure if something has changed, but the terraform docs now say verify defaults to false

Answer (score 2):

Solution/Workaround:
Download the chart-file by hand, save it to a local file and set

```
chart = "<path-to-your-local-file>"
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error when I ran `terraform apply` the first time on a freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04. The solution was running `helm repo update` manually the first time.

```
helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
    "bitnami" already exists with the same configuration, skipping

helm search repo bitnami
    WARNING: Repo "bitnami" is corrupt or missing. Try 'helm repo update'.
    WARNING: open /home/xxxx/.cache/helm/repository/bitnami-index.yaml: no such file or directory
    No results found

helm repo update
    Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
    ...Successfully got an update from the "cetic" chart repository
    ...Successfully got an update from the "bitnami" chart repository
    Update Complete. ⎈Happy Helming!⎈
```

Answer (score -1):

If the repo is not added to your local helm repo list then you get an error like;

```
Error: failed to download "https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/releases/download/cluster-autoscaler-chart-9.13.1/cluster-autoscaler-9.13.1.tgz" at version "9.13.1"
```

then if you add the target repo to your local everything should be fine

```
helm repo add [NAME] [URL]
```